# Proxmox CT have no internet connection, host trouble?

Tags: networking, proxmox

I have a CT with no internet connection but LAN is OK.
Another one with same configuration works. I try to restore a backup at a time CT works, but no sucess.
I can use LAN service of CT and ping some LAN IP, but not router IP and not resolv and ping something on WAN.

Maybe the problem come from the hostn but don't know what to do.

This is the CT config :

```
root@emeraude:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# --- BEGIN PVE ---
search home.aerith.fr
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 80.10.246.2
nameserver 80.10.246.129
# --- END PVE ---
root@emeraude:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.2
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1

root@emeraude:~# ip ad
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
25: eth0@if26: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2a:ee:e0:31:db:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::28ee:e0ff:fe31:db4e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is the host config :

```
root@rubis:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search home.aerith.fr
nameserver 192.168.0.1
nameserver 80.10.246.2
nameserver 80.10.246.129
root@rubis:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface enp4s0 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        bridge_ports enp4s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
root@rubis:~# ip ad
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:38:94:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: vmbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:38:94:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.4/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global vmbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::be5f:f4ff:fe38:94db/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
24: veth102i0@if23: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:98:ea:d6:da:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
26: veth101i0@if25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master vmbr0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:80:1e:1c:8c:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
root@rubis:~# brctl show vmbr0
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
vmbr0           8000.bc5ff43894db       no              enp4s0
                                                        veth101i0
                                                        veth102i0
root@rubis:~# ip route show
default via 192.168.0.1 dev vmbr0 onlink
192.168.0.0/24 dev vmbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.4
```

I am a noob, I think I break something on the host, please help. Sorry for bad english, I am french.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify what exactly works, ping to IP or to hostnames?
The configs look ok , I have just looked on my cluster and I do not see anything off. You have defined a default route on both host and ct.
If by any chance you mean that you cannot connect to hostnames/websites , anything related to DNS , the try to see the output or your resolv.conf file , maybe you don`t have defined a nameserver:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and if this is the case and is missing , just add it.